# How to use and link boost libraries in my own DLL

Tags: boost, dll

I am trying to write a dll that will basically be used as an interface to a device I have programmed. The idea is to have functions like getTemperature() and setTemperature(temp) that will send/receive messages over a serial port. As part of that there is a producer-consumer queue for which, I would like to use boost mutexes and condition variables.

I am new to dlls and boost and have written a basic dll which compiles fine. When I try to use it in another program, I get an error message when I run it. I'm using a german computer and so, the message is in german "Das Programm kann nicht gestartet werden, da libboost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_53.dll auf dem Computer fehlt. Installieren Sie das Programm erneut, um das Problem zu beheben". My limited German tells me this

"The program couldn't be started, because libboost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_53.dll can't be found"

I'm using code blocks with MinGW and have added the following link libries to my DLL project and also to my project that is using the DLL

- E:\boost\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
- E:\boost\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\thread\build\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\threading-multi\libboost_thread-mgw44-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
- user32

and I'm using the following defines:

- BUILD_DLL
- BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK

I have the boost directory included in the search directories

What am I doing wrong??? I imagine its something to do with static and dynamic linking but, I haven't had any luck trying to fix it

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

If I comment out everything to do with boost in my dll and recompile it, my program is able to run and call a function from the DLL that prints to the terminal.

**EDIT 2**
I had not included the paths to the boost libraries. By adding them to the linker search directories, everything worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is libboost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_53.dll on the path for your program ? This includes the current working directory.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have the folder listed  in my "Search Directories"

Comment: @Andre: There are many different "Search Directories", but the only ones relevant for loading shared libraries are: The directory where the executable is and environment variable `PATH` (and the manifest, but I have not seen it in practice).

Comment: You are right. I had not included the paths properly. It works now, thank you.